# "Cast a spell on people" vs. "cast a spell over people"?

Tags: prepositions

What's the difference between the two? Example:

> She cast a strange, yet beautiful spell **on** people.
>
> She cast a strange, yet beautiful spell **over** people.

Comment: Purely as a matter of style, ***over*** works better in your exact context, simply because it's coupled with the verb ***cast***. But if you'd used a different verb (without the metaphoric *cast = throw, fling, lob, toss, chuck* associations), that wouldn't apply. Idiomatically, it's always [*I'll put a spell **on** you*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27ll+put+a+spell+on+you%22), never *I'll put a spell **over** you.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers because cast over is more common than cast on?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. Consider [*cast a pall **on/over***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cast+a+pall+on%2Ccast+a+pall+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccast%20a%20pall%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccast%20a%20pall%20over%3B%2Cc0), and compare it to [*put a damper **on***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+a+damper+on%2Cput+a+damper+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20a%20damper%20on%3B%2Cc0) (where, again, ***over*** never occurs).

Comment: ...more dated (bordering on archaic), there's *Cast your bread **upon** the waters.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Over* can imply that *people* refers to a vast crowd of people and that the spell is cast upon all them as a whole.  This further makes the sentence possibly imply that you mean something like where a speaker "casts a spell over" his/her audience.

*On* would tend to imply that the effect is more about "any person" or individual people.